# how to create a select-field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

how to create a select-field?

please help solve the problem.

There is a table genders:

```
CREATE TABLE "genders" ("id"
    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "gender_name"
    varchar, "created_at"
    datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at"
    datetime NOT NULL)
```

There is a table users:

```
CREATE TABLE "users" ("id"
    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "name"
    varchar, "email"
    varchar, "password_digest"
    varchar, "remember_token"
    varchar, "phone"
    varchar, "skype"
    varchar, "info"
    varchar, "gender_id"
    integer DEFAULT 1, "created_at"
    datetime NOT NULL, "updated_at"
    datetime NOT NULL, "diary_name"
    varchar, "views_diary"
    integer DEFAULT 0, "admin"
    boolean DEFAULT 'f')
```

in model 'User':

```
GENDER_TYPES = [['Lisbon', 1], ['Madrid', 2]]
```

in view 'new.html.erb':

```
<%= form_for(@user) do  |f| %>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field  :name %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= f.label :gender  %>
    <%= f.select :gender,  User::GENDER_TYPES %>
  </div>  
<% end %>
```

but it not worked. The problem is that after a form submit value is not recorded in 'users.gender_id'

Answer (score 1):

Your select should be setting `gender_id`, not `gender`:

```
<%= f.select :gender_id,  User::GENDER_TYPES %>
```